# Load Facebook Like Box after page content finished loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, timeout, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to delay the [Facebook Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) from loading before the page content has been loaded in. I'm attempting to achieve this via AJAX but have so far had mixed results. What I did was take the code below (HTML5 version):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=147395032005356";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" data-width="292"   data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
```

...and had it sat on its own somewhere on my website.

I then setup some jQuery to get the code and append it to the page like so:

```
// set 1 second timeout
setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/facebook/likebox.php",
        success: function(data){

            // add loaded data to page
            $('#foo').append(data);
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

In some instances (hitting F5 on the same page) this worked and some it didn't.

I was wondering whether there are any better solutions for what I'm trying to accomplish, or whether I have actually overlooked something.

Comment: Why are you using setTimeout? if you are waiting for the document to be ready, there's a function for that in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @MichaelPryor I use `setTimeout` because I want to wait 1 second after the document is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your javascript into the fbAsyncInit() callback function so you can be assured that the Facebook JavaScript SDK has completely loaded before putting your like box.  Dont forget to call `FB.XFBML.parse()` after inserting the DOM for the like-box

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 $.ajax({
    url: "/facebook/likebox.php",
    success: function(data){

        // add loaded data to page
        $('#foo').append(data);
        FB.XFBML.parse($('#foo')[0]);
    }
 });
};
```